# Scrittura di alcune voci onomatopeiche con ripetizione

Tags: word-usage

C'è una ragione per cui 'tin tin' si scrive cosí piuttosto che 'tintin', mentre 'cricchi' si scrive così piuttosto che 'cri chi'?

Comment: Esiste *tintinnio*. Ma che significa *cricchi*? Indendi *cri-cri*, il suono del grillo?

Comment: @random, yes, I mean just it.

Comment: @random, e forse *gracchiare* deriva in qualche modo da *cricchi*, I don't know.

Comment: A me non risulta che esista "cricchi" in Italiano. Esiste "cricchio", il rumore del vetro che si frantuma (e anche "scricchiolìo"). "Gracchiare" viene da "crac", verso del corvo (voce onomatopeica).

Comment: @random, then, 'cri cri' is right, and so there is a parallel pattern in these words.

Comment: Sì, "cri cri" è il verso del grillo: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cri-cri/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treccani has [cri cri](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cri-cri) and also [tin-tin](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tin-tin/) (or `tintìn`): they are listed as *onomatopoeiae* (*voci onomatopeiche*).

Not to be confused with "[polyrematic syntagms](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/espressioni-polirematiche_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/)", when two or more words appear in a sequence such that the meaning cannot be inferred from the individual elements. A list [here](http://www.intratext.com/bsi/listapolirematiche/0-index.htm): it has `tam tam`, but not `tin-tin` nor `cri cri`.